# add html or body on click hide menu div

Tags: javascript, html

i have this code that if i click on the div ".jmp-container" , this will hide menu div .

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".jmp-menu-box").each(function(){
        let el=$(this);
        el.on("click", ".jmp-btn-group .m1", function(){
            el.find(".jmp-container").toggleClass("active");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
        }).on("click", ".jmp-btn-group .m2", function(){
            $("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop:0}, 200);
        });

        el.on("click", ".jmp-container", function(e){
            if(e.target==this)
            {
                el.find(".jmp-container, .m1").toggleClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

i want to change this part of the code :

```
el.on("click", ".jmp-container", function(e){
        if(e.target==this)
        {
            el.find(".jmp-container, .m1").toggleClass("active");
        }
    });
```

i want a code that let me hide the menu if i click outside div "jmp-container". this mean : if i click outside div jmp-container the result is : el.find(".jmp-container, .m1").toggleClass("active");

i want to do the toggle if i click on html or body instead of click on ".jmp-container" . **or if click outside the div ".jmp-container"** .
i tryed to do this :

```
el.on("click", "html", function(e){
        if(e.target==this)
        {
            el.find(".jmp-container, .m1").toggleClass("active");
        }
    });
```

but did not works .
can any body help me to get fix this issue ?
thanks

Comment: how can edit this code if(e.target==this) to tell the javascript to do the toggle if click outside the div .jmp-container ? this mean the target will be any element except .jmp-container .

Answer (score 0):

You can detect outside if it's `closest` parent has the required class or not.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  var elem = event.target;
  var closest = elem.closest(".jmp-container");
  if (closest) {
    // console.log("click inside")
  } else {
    // console.log("click outside")

    var el = $(elem)
    el.find(".jmp-container, .m1").toggleClass("active");
    // and if that doesn't work try *instead*
    //$(".jmp-container, .m1").toggleClass("active");

  }
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: wheat;
}

.container,
.jmp-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.special {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  top: 40px;
  background: blue;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    outside
    <div class="jmp-container">
      inside
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="special">
    special
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this is not what i want, i want a code that let me hide the menu if i click outside div "jmp-container". this mean : if i click outside div jmp-container the result is :    el.find(".jmp-container, .m1").toggleClass("active");

Comment: So instead of `console.log("click outside")` do `your logic`

Comment: i cant ... i dont know any things in java scripts . i tryed to replace console.log("click outside") with el.find(".jmp-container, .m1").toggleClass("active"); but get errors .